# Ajax Post request to Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, http-status-code-405

I have using ajax and spring mvc in my application.When users clicks register button, below codes work in my controller class called **UserController:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView registrationPage() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("registration");
    return model;
}
```

Registration page(registration.jsp) contains a form. I have using ajax request in this page.
  Below is the jquery ajax code:

```
function ajaxPostForUsername() {
var contextPath = "<%= request.getContextPath()%>";
var username = $('#userName').val();
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: contextPath + "/registration",
        data: {username: username},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType : "application/json",
        success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response == "USER_EXIST") {
                    $('.username-message').html("Username is exist.Please enter another!").css('color', 'red')
                    }
                else {
                    $('.username-message').html("Valid username").css('color', 'green');
                    }
            }
    })
```

}

and usage is in the form :

```
<input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="User Name" onblur="ajaxPostForUsername()" class="form-control"  autofocus>
```

In the controller called **RegistrationController**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String validateUsername(@RequestBody String username) {
    String jsonData = "USER_NOT_EXIST";
    if (userService.isUsernameExist(username)) {
        jsonData = "USER_EXIST";
    }
    return jsonData;
}
```

like this. I have added jackson dependencies in my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

So when i write a name in username field, the response is:

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

and the java console shows:

```
WARNING: Handler execution resulted in exception: Request method 'POST' not supported.
```

It looks like request works correct as you see in the picture. 
[Request-Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wasCq.png)

I have search it but couldn't solve it.So can anyone tell me what is the problem?
(PS:I have using spring security and added this in my form `<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>`)

Answer (score 1):

yo must add this to your ajax request

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token)
                  },
```

and this to your html :

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```